# Проблема с операциями над System.string, не могу парсить в double строку "2.456"

Tags: c#, строки

Есть ПО типа FastReports и в нем есть поддержка C#. Возникла проблема с одним отчетом (предыдущие 5 были сделаны без проблем), а именно с операциями над значением столбца из БД. Есть примеры написания скриптов для обработки данных для полей (картинка). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть поле со значениями value = "3.567" и якобы тип у него System.String, но операции типа `[Double.Parse(value)]`, `[Convert.ToDouble(value)]` - вызывают ошибку "Ошибка в выражении". Нормально только `[(string)value]` но выводит тоже самое естественно.
Задача: надо конвертировать данную переменную и округлить ее. Предыдущие отчеты не вызывали ошибок и `[Convert.ToDouble(value)]` или `[(double)value]` - легко конвертировали строку в double.
Еще момент. Для каждого отчета есть конфигуратор под блок кода (картинка). В данном отчете, этот блок пуст. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Какой DecimalSeparator установлен в системе?

Comment: Разделитель целой и дробной части: точка

Comment: Если, по Вашим словам, предыдущие отчёты конвертировали String значения в Double, то сравнивайте работающий и не работающий скрипт между собой...

Comment: Спасибо. Нашли решение. Нашли похожие данные с примененной функцией из блока кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там что-то намучено с десятичными разделителями. В "конфигуратор под блок кода" есть пример того, как делается конвертация с тем десятичным разделителем, который обнаружен в строке. Скопируйте себе метод FrmPr и используйте его.

Comment: FrmPr? А как быть с таким форматом? `1.000.000,00` Это вполне себе легальный сепаратор. Но метод вернёт неверный результат.

Comment: @aepot нужно исходить из входных данных. Если сам разработчик использует метод FrmPr, то он, наверняка, не использует разделитель тысяч. А так, конечно, замечание верное для общего случая. К тому же, я не знаю, есть где-то такая комбинация. У нас в качестве разделителя тысяч используется пробел.

Comment: В русском языке используется пробел для разрядов и запятая для дроби, и больше ничего не используется. Точка для дроби и запятая для разрядов - это в английском. А пример выше с точками в разрядах - в итальянском или португальском. Ну это как бы намёк, что парсер чисел должен зависеть от выбранной локализации, а не от наличия точки или запятой в строке. Как частный случай для автора, я бы сначала парсил в локали по умолчанию, а если не прокатило, тогда в инвариантной (она же английский).

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо. Нашли решение. Нашли похожие данные с примененной функцией из блока кода. Функция ниже:

```
 double ToDblDef(string s, double d)
 {
   double dd;
   if (Double.TryParse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, FrmPr(s), out dd)) 
      return dd;
   return d;
 }
```

Comment: можно писать `out double dd` и не объявлять заранее.